# Fetching Json string of C# datatable and displaying in jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Main thing is i am new in Jquery Datatable and from last 2 days I am trying to use it, using json string. But i am not getting require output.

**Here is my HTML :**

```
 <body>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="MydataTableDiv">
            <thead>
              <tr>
               <th>NAME</th>
               <th>MARKS</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Here is my Script :**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MydataTableDiv").DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        processing: true, 
        ajax: {
            "url": "../Home/GetData",
            "dataSrc":''
        },
        columns: [
            { data: "NAME" },
            { data: "MARKS" }
        ],
    });
});
```

And finally ,
 **My Home Controller :**

```
public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        DataTable _dt = new DataTable();

        _dt.Columns.Add("NAME");
        _dt.Columns.Add("MARKS");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            DataRow _dr = _dt.NewRow();
            _dr["NAME"] = "A_" + i;
            _dr["MARKS"] = i * 10;
            _dt.Rows.Add(_dr);
        }

        string JsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_dt);
        return Json(new {data=JsonResult }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Here is my Json string returned from controller :**

```
[{"NAME":"A_0","MARKS":"0"},{"NAME":"A_1","MARKS":"10"},{"NAME":"A_2","MARKS":"20"},{"NAME":"A_3","MARKS":"30"},{"NAME":"A_4","MARKS":"40"},{"NAME":"A_5","MARKS":"50"},{"NAME":"A_6","MARKS":"60"},{"NAME":"A_7","MARKS":"70"},{"NAME":"A_8","MARKS":"80"},{"NAME":"A_9","MARKS":"90"}]
```

This code gives me a blank and empty table which contains  all paging, filteration options.
please help me what is mistake in above code or is there any other way to use it for dynamic data.

Comment: can you verify what is the response from Ajax call in your network tab of developer tools? Is it what your datatable is expecting?

Comment: @G_S  it is given me , c# datatable in json format.

Comment: Is that what a datatable expects? can you post what you got in JSON format to your question if possible. (Because I expect that JSON is not what a datatable expects)

Comment: @G_S  I updated my question.

Comment: Check the answer provided and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

From what I have observed, datatables need a JSON object rather than a string. You are returning a string which can be converted to a JSON.

Made small change to your ajax call

```
ajax: {
            url: "http://localhost:21594/api/values",
            "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
                return JSON.parse(json);
            }    
        },
```

The above converts your data which you are returning as string to a JSON which datatable understands

Comment: thanx @G_S , I tried `json.parse()` but it shows wrong json format message.

Comment: So your json is in incorrect format then. verify your JSON again